# IPostbackEventHandler VS IPostbackDataHandler

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, events, postback

1)
User selecting an item in *DropDownList* is considered to be postback data, and for that reason *DropDownList* implements *IPostbackDataHandler*.

a) But why isn’t  user moving ( in *Calendar* control ) to another month also considered a postback data? Thus, why does *Calendar* implement *IPostbackEventHandler* and not *IPostbackDataHandler*?

2)
a) I assume that controls implementing *IPostbackEventHandler* instead of *IPostbackDataHandler* never receive postback data?

b) If control implements *IPostbackDataHandler*, then control’s postback event will be fired each time its data changed, even if that control didn’t caused a postback

But if control implements *IPostbackEventHandler*, then only time that control’s postback event will be raised is if that control also triggered a postback?

Answer (score 18):

1. DropDownList vs Calendar event interfaces:

   - The selection in the drop down list is considered data. You would submit the information in the drop down list  as data (in most cases).
   - Changing the selection on the Calendar control is considered an event, but not an event that submits data. It just triggers an event so that the code knows to change the control's state.

     The difference between these two is very subtle.
2. The documentation for [`IPostBackEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx) and [`IPostBackDataHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx) explain their purpose in the documentation, but they fail to make the distinction clear:

   - `IPostBackEventHandler` is used for triggering events that are not dependent on data, but on a user's action. For example, the `Calendar` control can trigger an event for when a date is clicked. This event is dependent on a user's actions, not the data the user entered.
   - `IPostBackDataHandler` is used for triggering events that are dependent on data in the control. For example, a `TextBox` has an `OnTextChanged` event, which should only be triggered if the text in the `TextBox` changes.

Comment: If I could, I would accept this answer in place of the guy that asked it and never looked back.

Answer (score 3):

To add, controls which implement IPostbackDataHandler does not rely on the view state for retaining data across postbacks.

Edit: But all controls depend on view state to retain visibility