# Question about events and custom server controls

Tags: asp.net

This is something which has always puzzled me.

If I want to make a custom control, in this case a child of the Datagrid control, but I want to ensure that when I hover my mouse over a specific cell, there is a rollover colour. If the datagrid doesn't have any provision of doing this (For argument's sake), do I have to get the co-ordinates of the mouse in relation to the cell and then highlight the closest cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rollover color should be defined using style sheets, or JavaScript. This would not be directly controlled through ASP.NET. You should have your server control generate either CSS classes to be used for defining hover styles, or generate inline JavaScript.

Using CSS is the best option, however it won't work in IE6 (and maybe IE7, I can't remember). This example assumes your control generates the data grid as an HTML table. Since your question says "custom server controls", this may be different if you're rendering your control with different markup. Make sure your table has a CSS class of `MyDataGridClass`.

```
.MyDataGridClass td:hover {
    background: #999;
}
```

If you want to highlight an entire row, you would change the `td` to `tr` in the example above.

If you want a hover style in IE6 and you only need to highlight a single cell, you can do better by using an `<a />` tag inside each cell. IE6 implements the hover pseudo-selector incorrectly so it only works on `<a />` tags, which is why this will work, but the above won't in IE6:

```
.MyDataGridClass a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.MyDataGridClass a:hover {
    background: #999;
}
```

This example assumes, of course, that you have the ability to embed CSS into the page your control will be placed on. If for some reason you don't have this option, you can go the JavaScript route, but this is not the preferred way to do things. If you're interested in seeing how you'd go about this using JavaScript, just let me know.

**UPDATE:**
The section below addresses the first comment you left. I've kept the original in case someone finds it useful.

---

In order to create an event driven control, you should implement the [`IPostBackEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx) or [`IPostBackDataHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx). If you need to understand the difference between these 2 interfaces, you can [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918561/ipostbackeventhandler-vs-ipostbackdatahandler/). I'd rather not include the details here because it would make this answer too long.

This example uses the `IPostBackEventHandler`, but the `IPostBackDataHandler` is pretty similar.

You need to do a few things to handle PostBack events:

- Create a key to use as an identifier for your event. This is used for the `base.Event` key/value collection. In this example, I'm using the `_EventClick` object.
- Setup/register your event with `base.Events[]` so that event subscribers are maintained across postbacks.
- When rendering your control, call `Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference`. This will generate a function call to ASP.NET's `__doPostBack` JavaScript method. You can use this script in any JavaScript event attributes you render.

This is a very minimal re-creation of the ASP.NET LinkButton control. Most of the "magic" happens in the `AddAttributesToRender()` and the `RaisePostBackEvent()` methods.

```
public class ControlWithEvent : WebControl, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    private object _EventClick = new object();

    protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
    {
        get { return HtmlTextWriterTag.A; }
    }

    public event EventHandler Click
    {
        add
        {
            base.Events.AddHandler(_EventClick, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            base.Events.RemoveHandler(_EventClick, value);
        }
    }

    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        // The value of the 'eventArgument' parameter will be "myOptions" 
        EventHandler handler = (EventHandler)base.Events[_EventClick];
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);

        // "myOptions" can be anything, including an empty string.
        // You can use it for your EventArgs object if you need it.
        PostBackOptions options = new PostBackOptions(this, "myOptions");

        string script = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(options, false);

        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, script);
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write(Text);
    }
}
```

If you want to include additional JavaScript logic with your control, I suggest you read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479390.aspx) on including JavaScript with ASP.NET to see how to register scripts with ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks. I won't need you to demonstrate anything else. I have an idea of how to use js to highlight a specific row/cell. I ask this question as I need to learn about custom controls and events (if you know of any good links, feel free to list them) :).

Comment: @dotnetdev I've changed my answer to align with what you said you were looking for based on your comment. Hopefully this is more of what you were looking for.

Comment: Actually, both answers were very useful. To recap, the easiest way of highlighting a row or cell in a datagrid is just through pure css which has the required styles (ensuring that css is part of the control through a skin etc). This is essentially the first method you provided, right?

Comment: Right. You should always apply styles (such as hover styles) using CSS if possible. It keeps a good separation of content, logic, and style which is what you should always strive for.